# .htaccess how to remove specific part after "/go=****" from url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a lot of spam links according to Goole webmaster such as (`example.com` is my site):

```
http://example.com/?go=xx.xxxxxxxxx
```

I want make redirect:

All links like `http://example.com/?go=xx.xxxxxxxxx` should go back to `http://example.com/` without `?go=xx.xxxxxxxxx`.

Appreciated any advice.

Comment: What is the `xx.xxxxxxxxx` part? Numbers? Letters? And to clarify, it is always requests for the root, with no URL-path?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^go=.+\..+
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com
```

`RewriteEngine On` enables the runtime rewriting engine, which is needed for the redirection.

The first `RewriteCond` is to match the query string in the URL with a regular expression, the expression `.+\..+` would match all URLs of the pattern `<domain>/?go=xx.xxxxx`.

Finally, we redirect all the query string accesses above to the base link with a regex expression that matches everything (`.*`), this is fine because we are using `RewriteCond` to check the condition.

Comment: Although this doesn't actually _remove_ the query string. It implicitly triggers a 302 (temporary) redirect to which the original query string is appended. It's also missing an `L` (or `END`) flag so might conflict with other directives. "a regex expression that matches everything (`.*`)" - although the OPs example only shows a request for the root (an empty URL-path), but even if you wanted to redirect _everything_, you don't need to actually "match" everything.

Comment: @MrWhite They wrote in the description that they want it to redirect, does this work for that or not? I'm not experienced with this and I answered it because there weren't any answers yet and I have some know-how. I think it would work for the use-case given (if it's wrong, can you explain it to me, thank you!)

Comment: Yes, it "redirects", but it does not "work". Crucially, it does not _remove_ the query string (ie. `go=xx.xxxxxxxxx`) - as mentioned - resulting in an endless redirect-loop. You need the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive (Apache 2.4+) or append a `?` to the _substitution_ string (Apache 2.2). This should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect in order to "remove" these _spam_ URLs (although a 302 is good for testing). Redirects should really be explicit, ie. use the `R` flag. eg. `R=301`. The above results in an _implicit_ 302 because of the absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the query string from URLs of the form `http://example.com/?go=xx.xxxxxxxxx` that target the document root only and where each `x` represents a character in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_` (underscore) you would need something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^go=\w{2}\.\w{9}
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `^$` *pattern* targets an empty URL-path only (ie. the document root) as shown in the example URL - rather than *any* URL-path.

The important part here is the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag that prevents the original query string being appended to the target URL (the default behaviour). Otherwise, the query string is not removed and this will result in an inifinite redirect loop. This does require Apache 2.4. If you are still using Apache 2.2 then append a trailing `?` (essentially an empty query string) to the end of the *substitution* string instead. For example, on Apache 2.2 change the above `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

`R=301` triggers a 301 (permanent) redirect - this is important if these were spam links that need to be *removed*. (Although you should first test with a 302 - temporary - redirect in order to check that the redirect is working as intended - this is to avoid any potential caching issues.)

The `L` (`last`) flag prevents any more mod_rewrite directives being processed that occur later in the `.htaccess` file. Without this flag you could potentially get conflicts that result in an invalid redirect. Generally, external redirects should always use the `L` (or `END`) flag.